# How to add buttons to a Perspective next to the View tabs in an Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I got a Perspective with a lot of Views attached to it (tabs on top, like the Package Explorer tab). I wish to put buttons next to the tabs like in the attached image. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your question precisely, because I can interpret it two different ways. I try to address both.

In both cases, you should specify commands (see the corresponding [vogella.de tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCommands/article.html) for details).

1. If you want to put a button next to a view header, you need two things:

   1. You have to position and size your view to have some space next to the header - if no space is available, the buttons will show in a toolbar below the header.
   2. You have to add commands to the toolbar:«viewid» menu location
2. If you want to add commands next to the perspective switcher, then the menu ID to use is toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.trim.command2. I got this one from the Mylyn ui project (org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui project).

Comment: This is the 1. case. I don't see how the 2. would be applicable here.